# About the Potential Form of Verbs 「られる」

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, godan-verbs, ichidan-verbs

The Potential Form (can) usually is conjugated by replacing whatever verb ending is based on the verb group.
However, I noticed that some verbs such as たべられる can also be written as たべれる. What's the distinction between using られる and れる? Moreover, can this also be applied to ichidan verbs?

Comment: Also, note that 食べる is an ichidan verb. I guess you meant to ask whether it can be applied to godan verbs.

Answer (score 0):

In a phenomenon called ら抜き, 'ra-omission', the *potential* form of the 下一段 and 上一段 活用, as well as that of the カ変活, I believe, can be truncated to merely ～れる. This omission is rather marked in its colloquiality, and is consequently frowned upon formally.